# The weak derivative u' of u vanishes on almost all points that u vanishes

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

In the book [1], it seems to me that the proof of Theorem 8.12 subtly uses the following result.

My question: Is the following result indeed true? And, is my proof of this result correct?
(If anybody is interested in supplying an easier proof, that would also be interesting).

**Proposition:**
Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval, $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ and $u \in W^{1,p}(I)$.
Let $S = \{ x \in I : u(x) \neq 0 \}$ (here we have fixed a choice of representative for $u$).
Then $u' = u' \chi_S$ a.e. on $I$.

**Proof:**
We first consider the $1 \leq p < \infty$ case.
Let $G \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $|G(x)| \leq |x|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and

$G(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \quad \textrm{if } |x| \leq 1, \\
x & \quad \textrm{if } |x| > 2.
\end{cases}$

Set $G_n(x) = (1/n) G(nx)$ and $u_n(x) = G_n(u(x))$ for each $n \geq 1$.

By Corollary 8.11 of [1] we have that $u_n \in W^{1,p}(I)$ with
$u_n'(x) = G_n'(u(x)) u'(x) = G'(n u(x)) u'(x)$.
Also, we see that $u_n(x) \rightarrow u(x)$ and $u_n'(x) \rightarrow u'(x) \chi_S (x)$
pointwise for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. An easy application of dominated convergence therefore yields that $u_n \rightarrow u$ in $L^p(I)$ and $u_n' \rightarrow u' \chi_S$ in $L^p(I)$.
Since $u_n \in W^{1,p}(I)$ for all $n$, this implies that $u' = u' \chi_S$ a.e. on $I$.
This completes the proof for $1 \leq p < \infty$.

Lastly, consider the $p = \infty$ case. Assume that $u \in W^{1, \infty}(I)$.
Let $J \subset I$ be a bounded interval.
Then $u \in W^{1,p}(J)$ for any $1 \leq p < \infty$.
From our work above it follows that $u' = u' \chi_S$ a.e. on $J$.
We conclude that $u' = u' \chi_S$ a.e. on $I$
since $J$ was any arbitrary bounded interval.

---

[1]: "Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and PDEs" by Haim Brezis